# Return empty result?

Tags: android

i creata an app to convert USD to Euros, require that when nothing typed, it will not apear the result. I code like this :

```
case R.id.main_btn_convert:

        String input = mTvBaseCurrency.getText().toString();


        if (input.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Type the number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mTvBaseCurrency = null;

            Log.i("String", ",asdkns,adkjsahd ");
            break;
        }

        else {


            String url = currencyUtils.createUrl(strBase, strTarget, input);
            Log.i("String", "url= " + url);

            currencyUtils.handlerJson(url);

            String result = currencyUtils.getStringResult();
            Log.i("String ", "result" + result);

            mTvTargetCurrency.setText("" + result);
            break;
        }
```

Problem begin apear, at 1st click (no input data), it OK, but when 2nd click it have error : force close app. This í my logcat
http://s17.postimg.org/6uaprjm5b/Untitled.png
Please help me fix this.

Comment: What is at line 200 of `MainPageActivity`? You don't need a `break` in `if/else`

Comment: String input = mTvBaseCurrency.getText().toString();

Comment: This is to get string that i type :)

Comment: `mTvBaseCurrency` is `null` for some reason. What happens after this code runs the first time? Does the `layout` change?

Comment: You should `break` after the `if/else` inside the `case`

Comment: How a 180x100 image would help decoding your logcat?

Comment: @codeMagic : at 2nd click, app close, this is notice : the application convert has stopped unexpectedly... I tried break after if/else like you said,but same problem

Comment: Yes, that's not your direct problem but not necessary. You change `mTvBaseCurrency` to `null` in `if`...why? That's why I asked if you change your `layout`. If not, then that variable is `null`, hence your problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are setting `mTvBaseCurrency` to null if it passes `matches("")`. Simply remove the following line:

```
mTvBaseCurrency = null;
```

Comment: mTvBaseCurrency = null; to return empty result when nothing typed :(.

Comment: @ItDn Of what I see you're gonna return an empty result without it too. You won't get into the else-clause if you get into the if-clause. Otherwise, you can always create a boolean or something else to check if there's a result or not.